# Удаление ячейки по нажатию кнопки

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

У меня есть таблица и xib Cell. На эту ячейку я добавил лейбл и кнопку. Как по нажатии на кнопку удалять всю ячейку из таблицы ??

```
import UIKit

class PlayerListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    //MARK:Outlets
    @IBOutlet var removePlayerButtonOutlet: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var playerNameLabel: UILabel!

    //MARK: Actions
    @IBAction func removePlayerButtonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
//DELETE CELL ?

    }


    //MARK:Override func
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }


}
```

Comment: Сделать вью контроллер (ну или презентер, зависит от архитектуры) делегатом ячейки и вызывать метод делегата для обновления и удаления этой строки в таблице

Comment: Первая же ссылка в гугле...
https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-remove-cells-from-a-uitableview

Comment: Это не совсем то, здесь нужно из самой ячейки вызвать удаление )

Answer (score 0):

Исходя из комментария @OlegSoloviev могу предложить следующее:

1. Создаёте делегат для каждой ячейки, например:

```
protocol CellDelegate: AnyObject {
    func updateButtonTapped(sender: UITableViewCell)
    func deleteButtonTapped(sender: UITableViewCell)
}
```

`sender: UITableViewCell` заменяете на свой класс

2. В методах-обработчиках делегата пишите нечто вроде этого:

```
func removeButtonTapped(sender: UITableViewCell) {
    guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: sender) else {
        print("Can't get indexPath")
        return
    }
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
}
```

Для апдейта сами сделаете, суть вы должны были понять


P.S. Или воспользуйтесь идеей @OlegSobolev она весьма легка и удобна в реализации